# How to delete azure tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

[image]

I was learning Azure AD long back ago then I created this tenant. Now When I am trying to delete the tenant then it shows the error( shown in screenshot above). How should I deal with this  situation? When I am trying to do something then it is showing **You do not have access**.

Answer (score 0):

First sign in with a with a global administrator or subscription administrator role.

Then just click on the manage tenant tab in azure ad.
[image]

Then select the tenant you want to delete click delete.
[image]