# How do i delete (or remove me from) the 'microsoft' tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

For some reason, in my 'switch directories' blade in azure, i see a 'Microsoft' Tenant listed. The tenant actually seems to be a 'microsoft owned' tenant. (id 72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47).

I assume i was added there once because of the MVP programm or related stuff - i am not sure, where this tenant is coming from. Using my access rights, when listing the resources, none are listed. However, a tenant without resources is creating problems for several scripts. Thus, i would like to remove this tenant from the list of 'my' tenants or remove me from this tenant.

I found this related ( [How to delete azure tenant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73043659/how-to-delete-azure-tenant) ) stackoverflow question. The advise is to select the tenant and press "delete". When i do this, i end up in some kind of never-ending-loging loop. Of course i also should not be able to delete this tenant, as i never created it.

Also, i tried the "leave tenant" button. This opens a "sing in" message which does not accept my credentials.

How do i get rid of that tenant?

[image]

Comment: There are scenarios where the organization you want to leave doesn’t allow users to leave by themselves. In such cases, you need to contact *Global Administrator* of that tenant to remove the guest user account.

 In your scenario, you may need to raise Azure **support request** with Microsoft where they delete your guest user account from Microsoft-owned tenant. Check similar issue [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1203398/leave-azure-ad-organization-for-locked-account).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, i cannot raise a support request as i do not have a support plan. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can post same question in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/) forum where Microsoft will get back to you for resolving the issue.

Comment: I will try but that would the 1st time ever, that i would have received a useful answer in that forum.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to post in microsoft q&a where someone from microsoft opened an internal support request to resolve this issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1395465/how-do-i-delete-(or-remove-me-from)-the-microsoft